# Java Sound API Detect Hot-plug Audio Device Slow

Tags: java, javasound

I'm learning Java Sound API to capture and playback audios. It worked fine with built-in sound card of laptop, which is a "Realtek".

In addition, I have a USB headset with audio adapter, which is a "Plantronics". Once I plugin the "Plantronics" USB headset, the Java Sound API only able to detect the Mixer of USB headset with a delay more than 1 minute. Vice verse, If unplug the USB headset, the Java Sound API only able to clear the historical Mixer of USB headset with a delay.

Following are the source codes I used to retrieve audio device and detect hot-plug audio device:

1) Retrieve audio device:
I used audio device name instead of the Mixer index to detect the audio devices is due to the Mixer index of hot-plug USB headset is dynamically changed everytime if plug-in or plug-out.

```
public static Mixer getMixer(final String mixerName,
        final String mixerDesc) {
    Mixer mixer = null;

    if (mixerName != null) {
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        logger.trace("Mixer infos list size[" + mixerInfos.length + "]");
        for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfos.length; i++) {
            if (mixerInfos[i].getName().contains(mixerName)
                && (mixerDesc == null || mixerDesc.length() == 0
                   || mixerInfos[i].getDescription().contains(mixerDesc))) {
                mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfos[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return mixer;
}
```

2) Detect hot-plug audio device:

```
private void doCheckMixerAvailability() {
    while (true) {

        Mixer newMixer = null;
        if (mixerName != null && mixerDesc != null) {
            newMixer = AudioUtil.getMixer(mixerName, mixerDesc);
        }

        if (newMixer != null) {
            getLogger().trace("Get new Mixer based on mixerName[" + mixerName
                    + "], mixerDesc[" + mixerDesc + "]");
        }

        // check current mixer and target line
        if (mixer != null && targetLine != null) {
            // if current mixer and target line are not NULL, check whether new mixer is NULL
            if (newMixer == null) {
                // reset members
                mixer = null;

                targetLine.stop();
                targetLine.flush();
                targetLine.close();
                targetLine = null;

                getLogger().trace("Audio port [" + this.getPortId() + "] with mixerName[" + mixerName
                            + "], mixerDesc[" + mixerDesc + "] become NOT available");
                // callback if listener is set
                if (getAvailableListener() != null) {
                    getAvailableListener().availableChange(false, this.getClass(), this.getPortId());
                    getLogger().trace("clear targetLine with format [" + getAudioFormat()
                            + "after mixerName[" + mixerName + "], mixerDesc["
                            + mixerDesc + "] become NOT available");
                }
            }
        } else {
            // if current mixer is NULL or target line is NULL, check whether new mixer is not NULL
            if (newMixer != null) {
                // update members
                mixer = newMixer;

                // try to create target line
                createTargetLine();
                // check whether create target line succeeded
                if (targetLine != null) {
                    getLogger().trace("Audio port [" + this.getPortId() + "] with mixerName[" + mixerName
                                + "], mixerDesc[" + mixerDesc + "] become available");

                    // callback if listener is set
                    if (getAvailableListener() != null) {
                        getAvailableListener().availableChange(true, this.getClass(), this.getPortId());
                        getLogger().trace("create targetLine with format [" + getAudioFormat()
                                + "after mixerName[" + mixerName + "], mixerDesc["
                                + mixerDesc + "] become available");
                    }
                } else {
                    // reset current mixer again
                    mixer = null;
                }
            }

        } // end check current mixer and target line

        try {
            Thread.sleep(checkMixerIntervalMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            getLogger().debug("CheckMixerAvailability thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I think Java is cache the Mixer information somewhere in lower level. If the assumption is right, is there anyway to not keep the Mixer information cache ? If not, is there other alternative way to efficiently detect hot-plug audio device by using Java or Java libraries ?

Thanks for your kindly sharing.

Comment: I do know that PortAudio in C is a good library to use and handle audio processing. Just want to know any stable Java binding of PortAudio can be used and eliminate this detect delay ?

Comment: As this ties into the native audio system of the underlying platform: Which platform are you using?

Comment: Also, such a huge delay smells like a bug to me. Please report it at http://bugreport.java.com/ so that the situation improves in the future. Most likely Oracle/OpenJDK isn't even aware that this is an issue. Thanks!